# Detect :first-child support

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

How to detect, using JavaScript, if the browser supports the CSS `:first-child` selector?

Comment: Do you *need* to detect it? :) It's supported on just about everything current: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17

Comment: ... check if the jQuery version is [≥1.1.4](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)? :p

Comment: @Kenny make that an answer - that is all the OP needs to check for

Comment: @Kenny, @Pekka - **jQuery** supporting it, and the **browser** supporting it (as a CSS selector) are two different things...

Comment: @Nick yes, but the OP explicitly asks for jQuery, doesn't he? In which case Kenny's answer actually is all he needs to know.

Comment: @Pekka - jQuery's in the tags, but he's asking if the browser supports it in the question...it's a questionable assumption at best I'd say.

Comment: @WorkingHard: Do you mean the `:first-child` selector *used in CSS* `li:first-child { text-decoration: blink; }` or *used in jQuery* `$('li:first-child').css('text-decoration', 'blink')`?

Comment: @Nick at the time I loaded the question, it explicitly said something to the effect of `How to detect support for :first-child selector in jQuery`? But I assume he meant, how to detect support *using* jQuery. It is clearer now.

Comment: I added the [css-selectors] tag.

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? :first-child is supported everywhere except IE6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use that `:first-child` rule to set some specific value, and then get the computed style in Javascript to see if the `:first-child` rule is applied, e.g.

```
<style>
#foo { width: 200px; }
#foo:first-child { width: 400px; }
</style>

<span><span id="foo"></span></span>

<script>
if ($('#foo').width() < 400)
   alert('first-child not supported.');
</script>
```

(This is not tested. I have no IE 6.)

Comment: This is nice and an exact answer to the question, +1. Although I have the feeling the basic premise of *having to find this out in the first place* is the result of a faulty design decision.

Comment: @WorkingHard: what extra block?

Comment: @WorkingHard what are you talking about?

Comment: @WorkingHard true. But I don't think you'll get around introducing an element like that (although you should be able to set `display: none` so it's hidden). Still, the basic question to me still is: *Why do you need this?*

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a jQuery function to find out support for this. I expect if it does exist, it is going to be quite complicated. Are you really sure you need this? Care to share why?

If you can use jQuery anyway, why not add a jQuery statement to assign the class/property/whatever to the desired element, instead of relying on CSS?

As a "manual" answer, looking at the [quirksmode.org compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), the selector is fully supported in all modern browsers except the IE family which seems to have problems even in IE8.

Comment: Ive found this page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/ but dont know how to use it

Comment: @WorkingHard: jQuery.support cannot test for `:first-child` support.

Comment: @WorkingHard I would ask myself first *why* I need this in the first place.